# Level separation height in Forest seems to have no effect

Tags: forest

How can I increase level separation to keep the tree nodes aligned when the node texts include the line breaks? `l sep` seems to have no effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    for tree={draw=black,align=center,l sep=6em},
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=10pt,
}
[P\\1\\2
  [N1\\1\\2,name=_N1
    [N1C1\\1\\2]
    [N1C2,name=_N2]
  ]
  [N2
    [N2C1]
    [N2C2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just introduced some phantom text.  I also changed the anchor depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
    for tree={draw=black,align=center,l sep=6em},
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-25pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=10pt,
}
[P\\1\\2
  [N1\\1\\2,name=_N1
    [N1C1\\1\\2]
    [N1C2,name=_N2]
  ]
  [N2\\~\\~,name=N2
    [N2C1]
    [N2C2]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Having 2 `l sep` caused the issue I think as one was overriding another.

Comment: If you would like me to delete my answer, just let me know that you've solved the issue through other means.